# Modify a http request

Tags: java, networking, proxy

In my host file, is have a url pointing to localhost which goes to my java program. This works fine when my program is on port 80 but nothing else. I would like it to run on different ports.

Say I want it to run on port 5, I know I have to proxy the program that's requesting the url and change url:80 to url:5. I just don't know to do it or find an open sourced proxy that does this.

The 'requester' is vlc so I can't change the url it requests. Ex: I open xyz.com in vlc then vlc sees the url I need to change the port for (not xyz.com).

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't see why you need a proxy at all. Just change the URL to use the new port number.

Comment: ugh, i left that part out. the 'requester' is vlc so i can't change the url it requests. i open xyz.com in vlc then it sees the url i need to change the port for.

Comment: So you need an HTTP proxy. There are plenty around. Search and recommendation questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score -1):

The  URL constructor adds the port number to the list of arguments used in the constructor:

```
URL newurl = new URL("http", "example.com", 5, "pages/page1.html");
```

This creates a URL object for the following URL:

```
http://example.com:5/pages/page1.html
```